# Disable other text boxes on input using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a form with several search (text) fields.  When text is entered into one of the fields, I'd like to disable the others.  Conversely, if all text is removed from the active text field, the other fields should be re-enabled.

The basic idea would be something like this (I think):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[@type=text]").keypress(function(e) {
        if(current textbox has text in it)
        {
            //disable all textboxes that aren't this one
        }
        else
        {
            //enable all textboxes
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not clear on what the easiest way to find/work with "all text boxes that aren't this one" is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way to do "all textboxes that aren't this one" is using the `not` filter like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":text").keyup(function(e) {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $(":text").not(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        } else {
            $(":text").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

#### Couple notes:

- I recommend giving a class to all the input elements you want to include with this behavior and doing a selector of input.myfields as it is faster/cleaner.
- Also, as of jQuery 1.3, the `@` in the selector is not supported. `:text` is shorthand for what you want, if are you sticking to selecting them that way.
- I also think you want the `keyup` event instead of `keypress`.

Comment: @type has been deprecated for a while, and no longer works in 1.3. :text is far more concise.

Comment: And it hasn't really been "a while"

Comment: Well, since 1.2. It has been removed completely from 1.3, so I wouldn't use it in an example.

Comment: Ok, well, I updated my answer with :text for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 2):

I would just disable them all first, and then since the code to be executed is triggered by an event for the control, you can use the this keyword to reference the control with focus and re-enable it.

```
$("input[@type=text]").attr("disabled", true);
$(this).attr("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd attach the login to the focus/blur events instead:

```
$(function() {
    $(':text').focus(function() {
        $(':text').not(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }).blur(function {
        if (this.value.length == 0) {
            $(':text').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})
```

@attr selectors were deprecated in 1.2, and have been removed completely from 1.3. In this case you'll want to use :text

Answer (score 0):

Use the [not](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector) selector